# Does anyone know if Hibernate and java will work effectively with Access?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, ms-access, spring

I have a small project that doesn't require much disk space, so i considered using an access database.

I was wondering if anyone used a Spring + Hibernate + access combination, if so can they post the connection properties.

thanks guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hibernate will theoretically work with any database that has a JDBC driver. Access does have a [third party driver](http://www.easysoft.com/applications/microsoft-access/jdbc-odbc.html), so in theory, yes it will work. YMMV.

Having said that, if you're requirements are for a lightweight database and you're working in Java/Hibernate land. I'd use [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) instead.

Update: The sticking point for using Access might be the SQL Dialect, In the Hibernate configuration you need to declare a class to tell Hibernate what dialect of SQL it is using. There is a list of [supported dialects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects), If any of these is 100% compatible with Access you could use that (I'm afraid I don't know which that would be, if any).

Comment: +1 to Derby. Derby is capable enough to replace My SQL or Oracle/SQL Express in several cases.

Comment: +1 for Derby. I'm using Derby (also known as Java DB) in a project I'm currently working on.

Answer (score 1):

The Hibernate [docs](https://www.hibernate.org/80.html) say that Hibernate has been tested against Access, but it requires a dialect from [HXTT](http://www.hxtt.com/hibernate.html).

Comment: Was any other answer besides mine voted down?  Why now, three years later?

Comment: You don't really answer to the question. This person says he works on a small project and you called him to take a paying driver. A paid solution isn't really a solution, otherwise it would suffice to answer: just pay $ 10 000 to IBM that they will make the solution. A computing question is not a problem of time, this is not a historic forum.

Comment: You've been here for twenty one days and you're going to lecture me about a three year old answer?  I was quoting the Hibernate docs!  And now a paid solution is required for a 64 bit operating system, because the DLL for the ODBC bridge driver isn't shipped with that JVM.  Sorry, you're off base here.

Comment: First of all, go tell the Hibernate people to update their docs.  They might say "We haven't tested against it, so we won't certify it."  Second, I don't go back and edit all my answers - that'd take too much time.  You can certainly downvote it, but my statement as written, even today, is not incorrect.  Third, your "answer" was deleted by a moderator who thought your "contribution" was inappropriate.  Read the FAQs, mister 21 days at SO.