# Using Hibernate with MS ACCESS 2007 Database (Free JDBC Driver)

Tags: hibernate, ms-access, jdbc, reverse-engineering

1.

I want to do a **reverse engineering** action with the **Hibernate** plugin of Eclipse on a **MS Access 2007** Database. I'm forced to use a existing MS Access 2007 db.

A easy solution is to buy the HXTT. But I want to use a **free driver** to do my work.

So I tried to apply this post : 
http://www.programmingforfuture.com/2011/06/how-to-use-ms-access-with-hibernate.html
(That uses the SQL Server dialect and the driver sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver)

Unfortunately I have an error that nobody seems to have been on the internet:

`Exception while generating code`

```
Reason : 
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error while reading primary key meta data for `c:/myaccessdb.mdb`.TableTest1
```

I have try to change the primary key on my MS Access DB (deleting all primary key) or to try the reverse engineering on a MS ACCESS with only one table without primary key, but I got all times the problems.

2.

*The purpose of my job is to transfer daily (weekly) an Oracle 11g database with data from an existing database MS ACCESS 2007. And I thought to use a procedure (Hibernate EJB) Java to be launched automatically every week to do the data transfer. Is this is the best solution ?*

Configuration :

- sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver v???
- Hibernate v3.4
- Eclipse

ps: If you are a HXTT developer or seller please be indulgent with my post ;). Making money by making people believe that you help, it's bad !

---

A solution is to use Derby Client driver, as the solution in the post: 
[Does anyone know if Hibernate and java will work effectively with Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154034/does-anyone-know-if-hibernate-and-java-will-work-effectively-with-access)

But a clarification of the answer of Rich Seller is required. Could you explain your answer and explain your configuration (hibernate.cfg.xml, persistence.xml and what URL you use in the property name="hibernate.connection.url") without using paying HXTT driver but with the free Derby driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only available solution is to connect your JDBC driver like that :

```
//Load the JDBC driver, useless with a Type 4 JDBC driver
Class.forName(DRIVER_NAME);

//To add specific properties such as a username/password pair
Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();

//Try to establish a connection to the database
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, connectionProperties);
```

And, then, make free reverse engineering is'nt possible...
The only way is to make entitiesManager whit yours beautifuls hands.

Have Fun!

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Hibernate forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=953517) the HXTT driver is the only solution currently available for using Hibernate with MS Access.