# how to connect MS access with hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

i need to connect the MS access database with hibernate can one help me..
          i am very confusion with what is driver class and how to configure with my eclipse
        your help very greate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749464/how-can-i-use-hibernate-with-ms-access

Comment: This is your 5th question on the site, for which you have obviously done absolutely no preparation whatsoever. We are not here to do google searches for you. If you can't lift a finger to try something yourself, we're not going to lift ours to help you.

Comment: No clear answer on google Marc B, so maybe stop assault people ? :) I have search on google during 7 days and no real answer have been founded. @Ramesh I'm looking for the same answer than you on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618065/using-hibernate-with-ms-access-2007-database-free-jdbc-driver
So I search on internet (and google) and I wait a good answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.google.com/#hl=en&biw=1143&bih=676&sclient=psy-ab&q=hibernate+with+ms+access&oq=hibernate+with+ms+&aq=2&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=hp.3.2.0l4.0.0.2.27.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.7fK3_x2Ytd0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=3ca401bf196c59f0